# Why does LiveScript use 'void 8' for undefined values?

Tags: javascript, void, livescript

I have been using LiveScript for quite a while now, and I have noticed that in situations where `undefined` would be implicitly returned, the expression `void 8` is used instead.

Naturally, I understand the use of `void`, but I cannot figure out why specifically the integer `8` is used.

For an example, the following LiveScript:

```
x = if truthy then \success!
```

Will compile to:

```
var x;
x = truthy ? 'success!' : void 8;
```

Comment: With some imagination, `void 8` reads like "voided". That must be it :P In any case, that's one of these questions you should ask the developers directly.

Comment: I guess it's the same reason most people use `void 0`.

Comment: I was thoroughly and hopelessly confused when I first saw this question because LiveScript was the original name of JavaScript in early Netscape builds where the scripting language first appeared and I was wondering what on earth someone was doing writing code for pre-NN4. So it turns out there's a new language, based *on* JavaScript, that goes by the name LiveScript... go figure.

Comment: @BoltClock Sometimes really new is well forgotten old.

Comment: I show my age, but to me 8 was always an error `JCL Return Code=8(Error) `

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation on LiveScript, here's their reasoning for using `void` rather than `undefined`:

> In JavaScript, undefined can be redefined, so it is prudent to use the
>   void operator which produces the undefined value, always. void at the
>   top level (not used as an expression) compiles to nothing (for use as
>   a placeholder) - it must be used as a value to compile.

As for the `8`, it's an arbitrary number, and could have been set to any other. As per discussion in the comments below, the reason for this particular arbitrary number is because LiveScript is a fork of coco, [whose wiki reports](http://github.com/satyr/coco/wiki/trivia):

> void 8 - the number 8 was chosen because it is a Chinese lucky number.

Regardless of how the developers chose the value, broadly speaking, it's just what the LiveScript `void` compiles to. There just has to be some expression evaluated by the `void` call.

Comment: Just wanted to add a note on why : it's a chinese lucky number

Comment: @Ven: As a Chinese, can confirm, but is that the reason behind this decision? Is the developer from a Chinese background?

Comment: @BoltClock gkz (LiveScript's main developer) isn't, but LiveScript is a fork of coco, the developer of which (satyr) is japanese.

Comment: see also [coco wiki](//github.com/satyr/coco/wiki/trivia)

Comment: @DarkKnight - good find! I updated the answer to include this info, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Most probably `8` is the favourite number of the developer (or just a random number), as whatever you put after `void` operator, you'll receive pure, not overridden `undefined`.

Simple test:

```
void 0    === void 8    =>    true
void 'a'  === void 8    =>    true
void true === void 8    =>    true
```